# Oracle - ANSI Encoding - KS5601 Character Map

Tags: oracle, encoding, character, cjk, ansi-sql

I will be deploying an application database on an existing Oracle Server. I need to store English characters on this database, but my client asked me if this would be a problem, since his Oracle database is using a “KS5601” character map, with “ANSI” encoding. My question is, if I create a new database on an existing Oracle Server instance, would this database have its own encoding, or it will have to follow the current encoding of the server?

If I have to use the KS5601 (Korean Character Map), would I be able to store English alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`KS5601` is not a database character set.  What is the existing database's character set

```
SELECT *
  FROM v$nls_parameters
 WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET'
```

What do you mean when you say "create a new database on an existing Oracle Server Instance"?  If you mean that you are creating a new database and a new instance on the same physical server (so you'll have a completely separate SGA & PGA and completely separate set of background processes), you can create the new database with whatever character set you'd like.  If you mean that you are creating a new schema in an existing database, you would need to use whatever character set the database uses.